# SQL Moving a Row to be a column - PIVOT query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given:

```
+-----------+---------------+-------------+-------+
|   Name    |   Location    | Description | Value |
+-----------+---------------+-------------+-------+
| Company A | Houston       | Sales       |   100 |
| Company A | Houston       | Profit      |    50 |
| Company B | San Francisco | Sales       |   500 |
| Company B | San Francisco | Profit      |   200 |
| Company C | New York      | Sales       |   200 |
| Company C | San Francisco | Profit      |   150 |
+-----------+---------------+-------------+-------+
```

How do I use SQL to transform it to:

```
+----------+---------------+--------+---------+
|   Name   |   Location    | Sales  | Profit  |
+----------+---------------+--------+---------+
| CompanyA | Houston       |    100 |      50 |
| CompanyB | San Francisco |    500 |     200 |
| CompanyC | New York      |    200 |     150 |
+----------+---------------+--------+---------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try either 1 or 2 query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bb33b/7

The second one gives the exact results shown in your question, but my guess is that rather the first one is what you are looking for.

```
SELECT Name, Location,
       Sum( Case Description when 'Sales' Then Value else 0 end ) Sales,
       Sum( Case Description when 'Profit' Then Value else 0 end ) Profit
FROM table1
GROUP BY Name, Location
Order by 1,2
;

|      Name |      Location | Sales | Profit |
|-----------|---------------|-------|--------|
| Company A |       Houston |   100 |     50 |
| Company B | San Francisco |   500 |    200 |
| Company C |      New York |   200 |      0 |
| Company C | San Francisco |     0 |    150 |
```

---

```
SELECT Name, Min( Location ) As Location,
       Sum( Case Description when 'Sales' Then Value else 0 end ) Sales,
       Sum( Case Description when 'Profit' Then Value else 0 end ) Profit
FROM table1
GROUP BY Name
Order by 1,2
;
;

|      Name |      Location | Sales | Profit |
|-----------|---------------|-------|--------|
| Company A |       Houston |   100 |     50 |
| Company B | San Francisco |   500 |    200 |
| Company C |      New York |   200 |    150 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your description values are only ever `Sales` and `Profit`, here is a CTE solution.  I called the initial table `Before`.

```
with cteSales as (select name, value from Before where description = 'Sales')
, cteProfit as (select name, value from Before where description  = 'Profit')
select 
distinct 
    name
    , location
    , (select value from cteSales where name = B.name) as Sales
    , (select value from cteProfit where name = B.name) as Profit
from Before B
```

Answer (score 0):

To transform your data to your desired form, you could do:

```
 SELECT NAME
          ,LOCATION
          ,SUM (CASE WHEN DESCRIPTION = 'Sales' THEN Values ELSE 0 END) AS SALES
          ,SUM (CASE WHEN DESCRIPTION = 'Profit' THEN Values ELSE 0 END) AS PROFIT
 FROM yourtable
 GROUP BY NAME
               ,LOCATION
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **PIVOT** function to transform row values into column however it will provide slightly different but more reasonable output -

```
SELECT Name, Location, Sales, Profit
FROM
(
    SELECT *
    FROM Table1
) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
  MIN(value)
  FOR Description IN (Sales, Profit)
) AS PivotTable
ORDER BY Name, Location;
```

Will generate the following output -

```
+-----------+---------------+-------+--------+
| Name      | Location      | Sales | Profit |
+-----------+---------------+-------+--------+
| Company A | Houston       | 100   | 50     |
+-----------+---------------+-------+--------+
| Company B | San Francisco | 500   | 200    |
+-----------+---------------+-------+--------+
| Company C | New York      | 200   | null   |
+-----------+---------------+-------+--------+
| Company C | San Francisco | null  | 150    |
+-----------+---------------+-------+--------+
```

You can use this as an alternate solution.